# how to save multiple files using phpexcel

Tags: php

i want to save 6 files which are in loop but only first file is getting saved.

code as below :

```
$dte=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dt));

$fname='Picksheet'.$dte.'_Zone_' .$zone.'.xls';
$filename='Backup.xls'; //save our workbook as this file name
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$fname.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name`enter code here`
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
//save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
//if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');  
//force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: where is your loop, where `$zone` come from, etc...

Comment: You can only send one file/response at a time to `php://output`... if you need to send multiple files, then combine them all into a zip, and send that zip file as the one file/response